# cannot input "empty" text into excel cells

Tags: c#, excel

[myExcelimage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cFD4.png)trying to insert "empty" text into excel cells that is empty.
PROBLEM : if excel row is longer than 35 rows all cells turn blank
i try using if (excelcell == null) then insert excelcell.value == "empty"

```
        range = xlworkSheet.UsedRange;
        rw = range.Rows.Count;
for (int row = 2; row <= rw; row++)
        {


            //if cells is empty insert error into the cells                               
            if (xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value == null)
            {

                xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = "empty";
                xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = "empty";
                xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7].Interior.Color = 
                      Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkOrange;
                xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Interior.Color = 
                  Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbDarkOrange;
                string in0 = "\t" + (String)xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 
                  7].Value.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(in0.ToString());


            }

        }
```

expect to get empty text in null cell ,but get blank instead.

Comment: What is the value of `rw`? Did you debug through the code? Did anything odd occur?

Comment: Try       `if (xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value2 == null)`

Comment: rw is the worksheet range value. if i read excel file that is more than 35 row I still get blank/nothing in excel and nothing in console.

Comment: value of rw = 847

Comment: @TimWilliams still does not work but thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value))
            {
                xlworkSheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = "whitespace";
                xlNewSheet.Cells[row, 7].value = "whitespace";


            }
```

the excel cell that i exported, all those empty cell is actually white space therefore if (cell.value == null)  statement is ignore.